# How do I wrap a curve around a tube?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I am modeling some kinetic balls ( or a Netwon's cradle) and I have some strings that wrap around the stand, like in this photo:

[image: Ref Image]
How would I go about this? I have tried using a bezier circle and *Curve* modifier method. Mind you I am using a path as the string. any ideas?

Comment: Please elaborate on why the curve modifier and circle didn't work.

Comment: the curve modifier didn't work, it turned my path into a very weird vortex-like shape.

Comment: play with the object origin point

Comment: @eromod please explain

Comment: @Optimusm please make the titles for your questions more descriptive and specific, so that your question can be understood without opening the post and looking at the image.

Comment: if you upload your .blend, I can make a .gif https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/where-to-upload-blend-files-non-expiring-links

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

*This assumes you are using a Subsurf Modifier on your cylinder.

Select your cylinder TAB into Edit Mode select one ring of vertices. Duplicate it by pressing SHIFT +"D". Then separate it by pressing "P" > Selection.

TAB into Object Mode and Press "H" to hide the cylinder (Just to make it easier to see your new circle)

Select the new circle and apply the Subsurf Modifier.

TAB into Edit Mode and select an appropriate vertex then place your mouse somewhere below it and CTRL + Left Mouse Click.

[image]

(Obviously only half you could use the Mirror Modifier to complete it).

When finished TAB into Object Mode and convert the object into a Curve.

[image]

Then you can use the Curve settings to adjust the curve how you like.

[image]

You will have to scale it up slightly so half of it is not in the original cylinder.

Comment: i am using a path not a cylinder, no need for subsurf

Comment: @ Optimus - If you use this method you do need the Subsurf to achieve "curved" edges between the vertices BUT you will need to "apply" it before converting the mesh to a curve.